# Can not access objects properties

Tags: macos, swift

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class Person {
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var age: Int = 30
}

let Bob = Person()
Bob.name = "Bob"
Bob.age = 60
println("\(Bob.name) is \(Bob.age) years old!") // Outputs Line1, seen below


let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "Bob")
let AClone = Person.objectsWithPredcate(predicate) // Searching for Person objects with name = Bob
println(AClone) // Outputs the Bob object
println(AClone.name) // Has Error1, seen below
```

**The outputs are:**

Line1: Bob is 60 years old!

**The Errors are:**

Error1: does not have a member named 'name'

This error is caused because technically AClone does not have a member named 'name' until after run time. Once the code has been run, AClone then has a member named 'name'. My question is, how do I tell Xcode that .name is a property that AClone will have after run-time? Is there a way for me to print AClone.name?

Note:
I have limited access to many sites due to my location in the world. Please excuse me if an answer to this already exists. If it does, please link to it and as soon as I can I'll take a look at the site.

Thanks!

Comment: try creating a predicate of class

Comment: objectsWithPredicate() sounds like it returns an array of objects. What about something like this: println(AClone[0].name)

Comment: "try creating a predicate of class", what do you mean by this.